# Extend TryFrom to use a generic error type

Tags: rust, traits

I am attempting to use `TryFrom` to convert types, except that I would like to use a generic error type. How can I extend `TryFrom` to cope with an additional generic error parameter?

```
use core::convert::TryFrom;

enum MyError<E> {
    UnexpectedValue,
    SomeGeneric(E),
}

enum MyEnum {
    Zero,
    One,
    Two,
}

impl TryFrom<u32> for MyEnum {
    type Error = MyError<E>;
    fn try_from(value: u32) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match value {
            0 => Ok(MyEnum::Zero),
            1 => Ok(MyEnum::One),
            2 => Ok(MyEnum::Two),
            _ => Err(MyError::UnexpectedValue),
        }
    }
}
```

I wondered if I could extend `TryFrom` into a new trait which incorporates a generic error parameter, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: _Why_ do you need it to be generic?

Comment: The code is part of an embedded driver (no std). A generic error enum with respect to I2C bus is commonly in drivers, so that it is device independent

Comment: For example, [https://github.com/fmckeogh/aht20/blob/master/src/lib.rs](https://github.com/fmckeogh/aht20/blob/master/src/lib.rs)

Comment: But who will decide what type it will get?

Comment: I guess the type would be given by the actual I2C implementation for the device used

Comment: But who will decide this?

Comment: Whoever uses the driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associated `Error` type of `TryFrom` is not generic and introducing a generic `E` (i.e. `impl<E> TryFrom<u32> for MyEnum`) would be unconstrained, so you cannot do this.

Likely your best route would be to create a distinct error type for your conversion with a `From` implementation that can convert it to your desired error type. That way, a `?` might convert transparently or you'd use `.map_err(MyError::<_>::from)` if it doesn't.

Demonstration:

```
struct UnexpectedMyEnumValue;

impl<E> From<UnexpectedMyEnumValue> for MyError<E> {
    fn from(err: UnexpectedMyEnumValue) -> MyError<E> {
        MyError::UnexpectedValue
    }
}

impl TryFrom<u32> for MyEnum {
    type Error = UnexpectedMyEnumValue;
    fn try_from(value: u32) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match value {
            0 => Ok(MyEnum::Zero),
            1 => Ok(MyEnum::One),
            2 => Ok(MyEnum::Two),
            _ => Err(UnexpectedMyEnumValue),
        }
    }
}

fn f() -> Result<(), MyError<()>> {
    let _e = MyEnum::try_from(5)?; // converts to MyError automatically
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good start, thanks. Annoyingly in my actual use case there is an existing `From` implementation which conflicts (`impl<E> From<E> for MyError<E>`) to convert other errors into the generic choice, which would conflict with this. Would there be a way to get round that?

Comment: @darkestelephant nothing particularly ergonomic. You could ditch `TryFrom` and use an inherent method instead that can have a generic return type. Or you can use the method above but ditch `From` and add an inherent method to convert from `UnexpectedMyEnumValue` to `MyError` generically.